# calling php page from wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have modified function.php in th wordpress and called php page from the wordpress menu using shortcode. I can able to connect and display php page.
In the php page able to display all the records intially without selecting value from dropdown list. But when I change the value in dropdown list instead of showing the filtered records depending on the dropdown list the page goes to wordpress index page. I suspect onaction command as a submit its not staying in the called php page instead it goes to the wordpress index page.

```
<?php
$selected = '';
function get_options($select) {
  $categories = ['Select Category' => 0, 'Information Technology' => 1, 'Management' => 2];
  $options    = '';
  while (list($k, $v) = each($categories)) {
    if ($select == $v) {
      $options .= '<option value="' . $v . '" selected>' . $k . '</option>';
    } else {
      $options .= '<option value="' . $v . '" >' . $k . '</option>';
    }
  }
  //var_dump($options);
  //echo var_dump($options)."<br>"; 
  return $options;
}

require_once('dbconnect.php');
if (isset($_POST['categories'])) {
  $selected = $_POST['categories'];
  echo $selected;
}
if ($selected == 1) {
  $selectedcat = 'Information Technology';
  $selectsql   = "SELECT * FROM courses where ccategory='$selectedcat'";
} else if ($selected == 2) {
  $selectedcat = 'Management';
  $selectsql   = "SELECT * FROM courses where ccategory='$selectedcat'";
} else {
  $selectsql = "SELECT * FROM courses";
}

//require_once('dbconnect.php');
//include('header-basic-light.php');

//$selectsql="SELECT * FROM courses";
$res = (mysqli_query($con, $selectsql));

if (!mysqli_query($con, $selectsql)) {
  die(mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_close($con);
//header('Location:index.php');
?>
<HTML>
<head>
  //<title>"View Information"</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
      <label for="categories">Select the Category : </label>
      <select name="categories" style="width:250px;" onchange="this.form.submit();">

        <?php echo get_options($selected); ?>
      </select>
    </form>

    <h2>View Information</h2>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>cname</th>
        <th>start_date</th>
        <th>duration</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
        <th>Options</th>
      </tr>

      <?php
      while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $r['cno']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $r['cname']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $r['start_date']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $r['duration']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $r['remarks']; ?></td>
          <?php if ($r['ccategory'] == 'Information Technology') {
            $catnum = 1;
          }
          if ($r['ccategory'] == 'Management') {
            $catnum = 2;
          } ?>
          <td><a href="loadpage.php?id=<?php echo $catnum; ?>">Details&nbsp&nbsp</a>
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to a category page whenever user changes your dropdown ?

Comment: try to change this part: action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"

Comment: I want to send to the same php page whenever dropdown value is changed and accordingly the detail records will be filtered.you can check from the website kkits.in->services->IT courses

Comment: Any clue? What changes to be done here?<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>

Comment: Done. In action I put "#". Now its is filtering properly and staying in the same php when I call from the wordpress.

Comment: Now I have another issue when I click the details(url). example this link http://kkits.in/services/courses/loadpage.php?id=1.  The following message comes  Oops! That page can’t be found.

It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try one of the links below or a search?

Comment: Thanks.. All Done.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of a short code is a requirement? Why not creating a page-*slug*.php, override it via a child theme and getting redirections and urls via standard permalink function?